# How can I let the superadmin user and user itself to access a API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `UserUpdateAPIView`, in it I can edit the user information:

```
class UserUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_admin=False, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False).exclude(status=4)
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer  
    lookup_field = "username"
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

The `UserDetailSerializer`:

```
class UserDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
"""
user detail
"""
class Meta:
    model = User
    exclude = [
        'password',
    ]
    depth = 1
```

Now, every user can access the `UserUpdateAPIView`, so its a bad design. I just want the super admin and the user itself can access the APIView, how to implement it?

I know I can use `permissions = [IsAdminUser]` to allow the admin users to access this API, but I just want to let the super admin user and the user itself to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.compat import is_authenticated

class IsAdminUserOrSelf(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # this methid is called in get_object method.
        # obj mean the object you retrieve.Here you retrieved is User instance.
        # It's can be any model instance,depend on the Molde you Retrieve in views.

        # if you want everyone can see user info
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        # if you use Django2.0 is_authenticated(request.user) should be changed to request.user.is_authenticated
        if request.user and is_authenticated(request.user):
            # is self or is superuser
            return obj == request.user or request.user.is_superuser
        else:
            return False

class UserUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permissions = [IsAdminUserOrSelf,]
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_admin=False, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False).exclude(status=4)
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer  
    lookup_field = "username"
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

Comment: whats the `obj` means there? do you mean it is the logined user? or do you mean the `obj` is the data(User's data)?

Comment: obj mean the object you retrieve,it's return by `get_object` method.Here you retrieved is User instance.It's can be any model instance,depend on the Molde you Retrieve in views.

Comment: I use `django-1.11.5`, how to import the is_authenticated ?

Comment: `from rest_framework.compat import is_authenticated`